# JavaScript for HTML :: I want to show multiple data into multiple filed for each Table Row

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show all data from each row into form filed. When I will click each row link then it will show each row data. But my javascript is not working well.

my code ::

```
    $('.cmcodedt').click(function(){
   var a = document.getElementById('cmcodedt').innerHTML; 
   var b = document.getElementById('cmnamedt').innerHTML; 
   var c = document.getElementById('ppunitdt').innerHTML; 
   var d = document.getElementById('ppunitqtydt').innerHTML;
   var e = document.getElementById('ppquantity').innerHTML; 
   var f = document.getElementById('pppurchasratedt').innerHTML; 
   var g = document.getElementById('pptotalamountdt').innerHTML; 


   document.getElementById('111').value= a;
   document.getElementById('222').value= b;
   document.getElementById('333').value= c;
   document.getElementById('444').value= d;
   document.getElementById('555').value= e;
   document.getElementById('666').value= f;
   document.getElementById('777').value= g;
  return false;
});
```

here is my screen::
[image]

My question ::: How do I show each row data when I click "1111"  or "product code" ?? It is working for single row only even I click another row.

Please help me. Note that I am learning javascript.

Comment: I i have understood correctly you want to display the data shown in the table in the input fields .Right?

Comment: Could you show the html

Comment: html is simple just <input id="111" > @daguru

Comment: See for my answer later today

Comment: Provide the html of your table please

Comment: are cmcodedt,cmnamedt,ppunitqtydt ..etc divs or input fields ?
same question for 111,222,333,444?

Comment: Besides, are you sure there is only one id and only one id in your html for cmcodedt..etc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) please check the fiddle [WORKING FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kULjj/41/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>Product code</th>
            <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Quantity</th>
            <th>Purchase rate</th>               
            <th>Total ammount</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>cmname_uu</td>
            <td>KLAX</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>132</td>
            <td>12.12</td>
            <td>1600</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>2222</td>
            <td>cmname_fr</td>
            <td>KLAX</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>55.77</td>
            <td>543</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>3333</td>
            <td>cmname_gg</td>
            <td>KLAX_HBMC</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>74</td>
            <td>65.88</td>
            <td>556</td>            
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="product-code" type="text"/>
<input id="product-name" type="text"/>
<input id="unit" type="text"/>
<input id="quantity" type="text"/>
<input id="unit-quantity" type="text"/>
<input id="purchase-rate" type="text"/>
<input id="total-ammount" type="text"/>
```

**JQUERY**

UPDATE (Row select on click)

```
$(".myTable tr").click(function() {
    var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    //change row color on click
    $(".myTable tr").each(function(index, elem){
       $(elem).removeClass("active")
    })
    $(this).addClass("active");  

    $("#product-code").val($.trim(tableData[0]));
    $("#product-name").val($.trim(tableData[1]));
    $("#unit").val($.trim(tableData[2]));
    $("#quantity").val($.trim(tableData[3]));
    $("#unit-quantity").val($.trim(tableData[4]));
    $("#purchase-rate").val($.trim(tableData[5]));
    $("#total-ammount").val($.trim(tableData[6]));
});
```

Comment: +1 nice approach, I didn't think of that, discarding all the messy id and classes thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are having an issue with assignment in the first part:

```
    ...
   var a = document.getElementById('cmcodedt').innerHTML; 
   var b = document.getElementById('cmnamedt').innerHTML; 
   var c = document.getElementById('ppunitdt').innerHTML; 
   var d = document.getElementById('ppunitqtydt').innerHTML;
   var e = document.getElementById('ppquantity').innerHTML; 
   var f = document.getElementById('pppurchasratedt').innerHTML; 
   var g = document.getElementById('pptotalamountdt').innerHTML; 
    ...
```

Notice the id here is `ppunitqtydt` and I suppose that each row of your table has a td with that id, ***right**?*Well, as the word ***id*** indicates, it should only be assigned to one dom element.

Inside the code that execute click on `cmcodedt`, it won't know that which `ppunitqtydt` you are looking for so it will fetch the first one available, hence, wrong data. 
Therefore an easy way to do it is to make `ppunitqtydt` as a class, and then access that class in ***relevance*** to the clicked element`cmcodedt`. In other words, if `cmcodedt` is clicked, then find the next sibling to it that has the class `ppunitqtydt` or `ppquantity` or etc.

If that is the case, then use something like

```
var a = this.nextAll(".cmcodedt").html();//this is the clicked element. 
$("#111").val(a);
```

**I haven't tested this personally, but that will be one general approach.**